# Class Initialization and Database Has_Many Relationship Raffle Tickets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, relationship, has-many

Here is my problem...I am setting up a game where several users can play a game with 10,000 raffle tickets.  Every game will have 10,000 raffle tickets and will not start until all 10,000 raffle tickets are sold.  That being said,  I have two simple classes in my DB, and for every game that goes, I need to initialize the 10,000 unique tickets for a single game relationship.  I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

models/game.rb

```
 class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tickets
 end
```

models/ticket.rb

```
 class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :game
 end
```

controllers/games_controller.rb

```
 class GamesController < ApplicationController

 def create
     g = Game.new
     g.winning_ticket_num = params["winning_ticket_num"]
     g.value_per_ticket = params["value_per_ticket"]
     g.save
     10000.times do 
       ticket = Ticket.new
       ticket.game_id = g.id
       ticket.nickname = "null"
       ticket.save
     end
 end 


 end
```

controllers/tickets_controller.rb

```
 class TicketsController < ApplicationController

def create
    t = Ticket.new
    t.nickname = params["nickname"]
    t.game_id = params["game_id"]
    t.save
end

 end
```

Answer (score 1):

After all the comments exchanged, let's summarize:

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @game = Game.new(params[:game])

    10000.times do
      @game.tickets.build(nickname: "null")
    end

    @game.save
  end
end
```

Game.new creates your game, based on the parameters in your view. The "winning_ticket_num" and "value_per_ticket" will be automatically "copied" to your new game object. You must make sure these parameters can be assigned to, either using strong parameters in Rails, or using attr_accessible in Rails < 4.0

The @game.tickets.build creates the 10000 tickets. The game's ID will be automatically assigned when the game is finally saved. Also the tickets themselves will be saved when the parent game is saved

Comment: Much cleaner answer than mine.

Comment: Did this solve your problem? If so, can you pls accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the IDs yourself, use [ActiveRecord associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html). Note that `tickets.create` will save the Ticket object to the database when it is created (which seems what you wanted to do above).

```
def create
  @g = Game.new
  @g.winning_ticket_num = params["winning_ticket_num"]
  @g.value_per_ticket = params["value_per_ticket"]
  @g.save
  10000.times do 
    @g.tickets.create(nickname => "null")
  end
end
```

EDIT: syntax error, the `=` changed to `=>`. Also remove the `ticket.` part. Sorry, this is what happens without tests.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply...using this code (literally subbing it in) I still am running into the problem in the console if I say g1 = Game.create...then I run Game.all I show the game, but when I run Ticket.all nothing is returned.  I'm still not sure what the problem is or if I am trying to access them wrong.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: From what I understand from your comment, you're trying to "test" the creation of the Game from your console using Game.create. This will indeed create a Game object, but won't execute the code in your controller! As such, no tickets will be created!

Comment: Ahhh thanks...so what is a good way to test that out...write up some simple html and display that once I have created a game?  Is there a faster way to test out the solution?

Comment: Two ways: write some simple view just calling your controller action (or use rails scaffolding to get a first version of each view for your actions), or use something like rspec/cucumber to do test-driven development...

Comment: I decided to write the simple views and this is the problem in the controller now...all of this makes good sense, but rails is having fits.           NameError in GamesController#create
undefined local variable or method `ticket'    
  @g.save
  10.times do 
    @g.tickets.create(ticket.nickname = "null")
  end
  render 'games#show'
end 
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/games_controller.rb:9:in `block in create'
app/controllers/games_controller.rb:8:in `times'
app/controllers/games_controller.rb:8:in `create'
Request

Parameters:

{"value_per_ticket"=>"10"}

Comment: remove the "ticket.". Just nickname = "null" will do

Comment: I totally removed the () altogether...nothing seemed to work with it, and I'm trying to display all of the tickets as they stand at the moment...I very much appreciate the help.

Comment: sorry. nickname = doesn't work. it needs to be a hash, or at least nickname: "null"

Comment: Thanks, Danny. I've corrected the answer. (nickname: "null") is equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

The thing i see that is wrong, If you are using form_for, then the params are params[:game]

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController

def create
    g = Game.new
    g.winning_ticket_num = params[:game]["winning_ticket_num"]
    g.value_per_ticket = params[:game]["value_per_ticket"]
    g.save
    10000.times do 
      ticket = Ticket.new
      ticket.game_id = g.id
      ticket.nickname = "null"
      ticket.save
    end
end 
end
```

So adding params[:game] will get the values

Comment: It's the same problem here as below...I must not be accessing the tickets right in the console from the database...however, I should be able to see the tickets using Ticket.all once I've created a game...They just aren't being created.  Thanks for the help.